# Vertical & Horizontal Scrolling in Listview

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to create a common listviews inside a  [horizontal listview](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). The horizontal scroll is fine, but the vertical scroll is not working. I've tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768952/android-vertical-scrolling-for-listview-inside-horizontal-scrollview) solution but nothing happened. What should I do?

HorizontalListviewDemo.java

```
package com.devsmart.android.ui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView;
import com.example.horlistview.R;

public class HorizontalListViewDemo extends Activity {

    private final static String ITEM = "item";
    private static int COLUMN_COUNT = 20;
    private static int ROW_COUNT = 50;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);

        HorizontialListView listview = (HorizontialListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    static class VerticalViewHolder {
        protected TextView textview;
    }

    public void setColumnCount(int n) {
        COLUMN_COUNT = n;
    }

    public void setRowCount(int n) {
        ROW_COUNT = n;
    }

    private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

        public int getCount() {
            return COLUMN_COUNT;
        }


        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final List<Map<String, String>> l = createList();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
            final ListView listview = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewitem_listview);

            if (position==0) {
                listview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()-50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                listview.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        l,
                        R.layout.viewitemitem,
                        new String[] {ITEM},
                        new int[] {R.id.textView}) {

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        VerticalViewHolder verticalViewHolder = null;
                        if (convertView==null) {
                            convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                            verticalViewHolder = new VerticalViewHolder();
                            verticalViewHolder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) verticalViewHolder.textview.getLayoutParams();
                            if (position==0)    lp.setMargins(1, 2, 1, 0);
                            else                lp.setMargins(1, 0, 1, 0);

                            convertView.setTag(verticalViewHolder);
                            convertView.setTag(R.id.textView, verticalViewHolder.textview);
                        } else {
                            verticalViewHolder = (VerticalViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }
                        verticalViewHolder.textview.setText(l.get(position).get(ITEM));
                        return convertView;
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                if (COLUMN_COUNT>=5)
                    listview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()/5, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                else
                    listview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(parent.getWidth()/COLUMN_COUNT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                listview.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        l,
                        R.layout.viewitemitem,
                        new String[] {ITEM},
                        new int[] {R.id.textView}) {

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        View retval = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView textview = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) textview.getLayoutParams();
                        if (position==0)                lp.setMargins(0, 2, 1, 0);
                        else if (position==ROW_COUNT-1) lp.setMargins(0, 0, 1, 1);
                        else                            lp.setMargins(0, 0, 1, 0);
                        return retval;
                    }
                });
            }

            convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    listview.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
                    listview.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        private List<Map<String, String>> createList() {
            List<Map<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            Map<String, String> v = new HashMap<String, String>();

            for (int j = 0; j < ROW_COUNT; j++) {
                v = new HashMap<String, String>();
                v.put(ITEM, ""+j);
                values.add(v);
            }

            return values;
        }
    };

}
```

HorizontalListView.java

```
/*
 * HorizontalListView.java v1.5
 *
 * 
 * The MIT License
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Paul Soucy (paul@dev-smart.com)
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */

package com.devsmart.android.ui;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.Scroller;

public class HorizontialListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

    public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
    protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
    protected int mCurrentX;
    protected int mNextX;
    private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
    protected Scroller mScroller;
    private GestureDetector mGesture;
    private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
    private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
    private boolean mDataChanged = false;


    public HorizontialListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    private synchronized void initView() {
        mLeftViewIndex = -1;
        mRightViewIndex = 0;
        mDisplayOffset = 0;
        mCurrentX = 0;
        mNextX = 0;
        mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
        mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        mOnItemSelected = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener){
        mOnItemClicked = listener;
    }

    private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            synchronized(HorizontialListView.this){
                mDataChanged = true;
            }
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            reset();
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();
        }

    };

    @Override
    public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
        //TODO: implement
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        if(mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
        }
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
        reset();
    }

    private synchronized void reset(){
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        //TODO: implement
    }

    private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
        LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
        if(params == null) {
            params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        }

        addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
        child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        if(mAdapter == null){
            return;
        }

        if(mDataChanged){
            int oldCurrentX = mCurrentX;
            initView();
            removeAllViewsInLayout();
            mNextX = oldCurrentX;
            mDataChanged = false;
        }

        if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
            int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
            mNextX = scrollx;
        }

        if(mNextX < 0){
            mNextX = 0;
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        }
        if(mNextX > mMaxX) {
            mNextX = mMaxX;
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        }

        int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

        removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
        fillList(dx);
        positionItems(dx);

        mCurrentX = mNextX;

        if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
            post(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    requestLayout();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void fillList(final int dx) {
        int edge = 0;
        View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        if(child != null) {
            edge = child.getRight();
        }
        fillListRight(edge, dx);

        edge = 0;
        child = getChildAt(0);
        if(child != null) {
            edge = child.getLeft();
        }
        fillListLeft(edge, dx);


    }

    private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
        while(rightEdge + dx < getWidth() && mRightViewIndex < mAdapter.getCount()) {

            View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
            addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
            rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

            if(mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1){
                mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
            }
            mRightViewIndex++;
        }

    }

    private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
        while(leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
            View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
            addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
            leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
            mLeftViewIndex--;
            mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
    }

    private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        while(child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
            mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
            mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
            removeViewInLayout(child);
            mLeftViewIndex++;
            child = getChildAt(0);

        }

        child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
            mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
            removeViewInLayout(child);
            mRightViewIndex--;
            child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        }
    }

    private void positionItems(final int dx) {
        if(getChildCount() > 0){
            mDisplayOffset += dx;
            int left = mDisplayOffset;
            for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
                left += childWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
        mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean handled = mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return handled;
    }

    protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
        synchronized(HorizontialListView.this){
            mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int)-velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
    }

    protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        return true;
    }

    private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return HorizontialListView.this.onDown(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            return HorizontialListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            synchronized(HorizontialListView.this){
                mNextX += (int)distanceX;
            }
            requestLayout();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Rect viewRect = new Rect();
            for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                int left = child.getLeft();
                int right = child.getRight();
                int top = child.getTop();
                int bottom = child.getBottom();
                viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
                if(viewRect.contains((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY())){
                    if(mOnItemClicked != null){
                        mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontialListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                    }
                    if(mOnItemSelected != null){
                        mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontialListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                    }
                    break;
                }                   
            }
            return true;
        }           
    };      
}
```

listviewdemo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#fff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

viewitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewitem_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/viewitem_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

viewitemitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewitemitem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try out my below code which is Customized `HorizontalScrollingPage` which provides the functionality to scroll the views vertically & horizontally containing the listview also..

**HorizontalPagerWithPageControl.class**

> ```
>   package com.wli.horizontalpager.withpagecontrol;
>    import android.content.Context;
>    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
>    import android.graphics.Color;
>    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
>    import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
>    import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
>    import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape;
>    import android.util.AttributeSet;
>    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
>    import android.view.Display;
>    import android.view.Gravity;
>    import android.view.MotionEvent;
>    import android.view.VelocityTracker;
>    import android.view.View;
>    import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
>    import android.view.ViewGroup;
>    import android.view.WindowManager;
>    import android.widget.ImageView;
>    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
>    import android.widget.Scroller;      
>    public final class HorizontalPagerWithPageControl extends ViewGroup {
> /*
>  * How long to animate between screens when programmatically setting with
>  * setCurrentScreen using the animate parameter
>  */
> private static final int ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS = 500;
> // What fraction (1/x) of the screen the user must swipe to indicate a page
> // change
> private static final int FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE = 4;
> private static final int INVALID_SCREEN = -1;
> /*
>  * Velocity of a swipe (in density-independent pixels per second) to force a
>  * swipe to the next/previous screen. Adjusted into
>  * mDensityAdjustedSnapVelocity on init.
>  */
> private static final int SNAP_VELOCITY_DIP_PER_SECOND = 600;
> // Argument to getVelocity for units to give pixels per second (1 = pixels
> // per millisecond).
> private static final int VELOCITY_UNIT_PIXELS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
> private static final int TOUCH_STATE_REST = 0;
> private static final int TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING = 1;
> private static final int TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING = -1;
> private int m_currentScreen;
> private int m_densityAdjustedSnapVelocity;
> private boolean m_firstLayout = true;
> private float m_lastMotionX;
> private float m_lastMotionY;
> private OnScreenSwitchListener m_onScreenSwitchListener;
> private int m_maximumVelocity;
> private int m_nextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
> private Scroller m_scroller;
> private int m_touchSlop;
> private int m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
> private VelocityTracker m_velocityTracker;
> private int m_lastSeenLayoutWidth = -1;
> // Active and inactive draw
> private Drawable m_activeDrawable;
> private Drawable m_inactiveDrawable;
> // The size for the drawables
> private float m_indicatorSize;
> // The screen scale to get px to dip
> private static float SCALE;
> /**
>  * Simple constructor to use when creating a view from code.
>  * 
>  * @param p_context
>  *            The Context the view is running in, through which it can
>  *            access the current theme, resources, etc.
>  */
> public HorizontalPagerWithPageControl(final Context p_context) {
>     super(p_context);
>     init();
> }
> /**
>  * Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML. This is called
>  * when a view is being constructed from an XML file, supplying attributes
>  * that were specified in the XML file. This version uses a default style of
>  * 0, so the only attribute values applied are those in the Context's Theme
>  * and the given AttributeSet.
>  * 
>  * <p>
>  * The method onFinishInflate() will be called after all children have been
>  * added.
>  * 
>  * @param p_context
>  *            The Context the view is running in, through which it can
>  *            access the current theme, resources, etc.
>  * @param p_attrs
>  *            The attributes of the XML tag that is inflating the view.
>  * @see #View(Context, AttributeSet, int)
>  */
> public HorizontalPagerWithPageControl(final Context p_context,
>         final AttributeSet p_attrs) {
>     super(p_context, p_attrs);
>     init();
> }
> /**
>  * Sets up the scroller and touch/fling sensitivity parameters for the
>  * pager.
>  */
> private void init() {
>     m_scroller = new Scroller(getContext());
>     // get the screen density
>     SCALE = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
>     // set the indicator size resolution independent
>     m_indicatorSize = (7 * SCALE);
>     // Calculate the density-dependent snap velocity in pixels
>     DisplayMetrics m_displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
>     ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
>             .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(m_displayMetrics);
>     m_densityAdjustedSnapVelocity = (int) (m_displayMetrics.density * SNAP_VELOCITY_DIP_PER_SECOND);
>     final ViewConfiguration m_configuration = ViewConfiguration
>             .get(getContext());
>     m_touchSlop = m_configuration.getScaledTouchSlop();
>     m_maximumVelocity = m_configuration.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
>     // draw the shapes
>     makeShapes();
> }
> @Override
> protected void onMeasure(final int p_widthMeasureSpec,
>         final int p_heightMeasureSpec) {
>     super.onMeasure(p_widthMeasureSpec, p_heightMeasureSpec);
>     final int m_width = MeasureSpec.getSize(p_widthMeasureSpec);
>     final int m_widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(p_widthMeasureSpec);
>     if (m_widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
>         throw new IllegalStateException(
>                 "ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
>     }
>     final int m_heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(p_heightMeasureSpec);
>     if (m_heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
>         throw new IllegalStateException(
>                 "ViewSwitcher can only be used in EXACTLY mode.");
>     }
>     // The children are given the same width and height as the workspace
>     final int m_count = getChildCount();
>     for (int m_i = 0; m_i < m_count; m_i++) {
>         getChildAt(m_i).measure(p_widthMeasureSpec, p_heightMeasureSpec);
>     }
>     if (m_firstLayout) {
>         scrollTo(m_currentScreen * m_width, 0);
>         m_firstLayout = false;
>     }
>     else if (m_width != m_lastSeenLayoutWidth) { // Width has changed
>         /*
>          * Recalculate the width and scroll to the right position to be sure
>          * we're in the right place in the event that we had a rotation that
>          * didn't result in an activity restart (code by aveyD). Without
>          * this you can end up between two pages after a rotation.
>          */
>         Display m_display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(
>                 Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
>         int m_displayWidth = m_display.getWidth();
>         m_nextScreen = Math.max(0,
>                 Math.min(getCurrentScreen(), getChildCount() - 1));
>         final int m_newX = m_nextScreen * m_displayWidth;
>         final int m_delta = m_newX - getScrollX();
>         m_scroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, m_delta, 0, 0);
>     }
>     m_lastSeenLayoutWidth = m_width;
> }
> @Override
> protected void onLayout(final boolean p_changed, final int p_l,
>         final int p_t, final int p_r, final int p_b) {
>     int m_childLeft = 0;
>     final int m_count = getChildCount();
>     for (int m_i = 0; m_i < m_count; m_i++) {
>         final View m_child = getChildAt(m_i);
>         if (m_child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
>             final int m_childWidth = m_child.getMeasuredWidth();
>             m_child.layout(m_childLeft, 0, m_childLeft + m_childWidth,
>                     m_child.getMeasuredHeight());
>             m_childLeft += m_childWidth;
>         }
>     }
> }
> @Override
> public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent p_ev) {
>     /*
>      * By Yoni Samlan: Modified onInterceptTouchEvent based on standard
>      * ScrollView's onIntercept. The logic is designed to support a nested
>      * vertically scrolling view inside this one; once a scroll registers
>      * for X-wise scrolling, handle it in this view and don't let the
>      * children, but once a scroll registers for y-wise scrolling, let the
>      * children handle it exclusively.
>      */
>     final int m_action = p_ev.getAction();
>     boolean m_intercept = false;
>     switch (m_action) {
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
>         /*
>          * If we're in a horizontal scroll event, take it (intercept further
>          * events). But if we're mid-vertical-scroll, don't even try; let
>          * the children deal with it. If we haven't found a scroll event
>          * yet, check for one.
>          */
>         if (m_touchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
>             /*
>              * We've already started a horizontal scroll; set intercept to
>              * true so we can take the remainder of all touch events in
>              * onTouchEvent.
>              */
>             m_intercept = true;
>         } else if (m_touchState == TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING) {
>             // Let children handle the events for the duration of the scroll
>             // event.
>             m_intercept = false;
>         } else { // We haven't picked up a scroll event yet; check for one.
>             /*
>              * If we detected a horizontal scroll event, start stealing
>              * touch events (mark as scrolling). Otherwise, see if we had a
>              * vertical scroll event -- if so, let the children handle it
>              * and don't look to intercept again until the motion is done.
>              */
>             final float m_x = p_ev.getX();
>             final int m_xDiff = (int) Math.abs(m_x - m_lastMotionX);
>             boolean m_xMoved = m_xDiff > m_touchSlop;
>             if (m_xMoved) {
>                 // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
>                 m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
>                 m_lastMotionX = m_x;
>             }
>             final float m_y = p_ev.getY();
>             final int m_yDiff = (int) Math.abs(m_y - m_lastMotionY);
>             boolean m_yMoved = m_yDiff > m_touchSlop;
>             if (m_yMoved) {
>                 m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_VERTICAL_SCROLLING;
>             }
>         }
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
>         // Release the drag.
>         m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>         /*
>          * No motion yet, but register the coordinates so we can check for
>          * intercept at the next MOVE event.
>          */
>         m_lastMotionY = p_ev.getY();
>         m_lastMotionX = p_ev.getX();
>         break;
>     default:
>         break;
>     }
>     return m_intercept;
> }
> @Override
> public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent p_ev) {
>     if (m_velocityTracker == null) {
>         m_velocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
>     }
>     m_velocityTracker.addMovement(p_ev);
>     final int m_action = p_ev.getAction();
>     final float m_x = p_ev.getX();
>     switch (m_action) {
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>         /*
>          * If being flinged and user touches, stop the fling. isFinished
>          * will be false if being flinged.
>          */
>         if (!m_scroller.isFinished()) {
>             m_scroller.abortAnimation();
>         }
>         // Remember where the motion event started
>         m_lastMotionX = m_x;
>         if (m_scroller.isFinished()) {
>             m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
>         } else {
>             m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
>         }
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
>         final int m_xDiff = (int) Math.abs(m_x - m_lastMotionX);
>         boolean m_xMoved = m_xDiff > m_touchSlop;
>         if (m_xMoved) {
>             // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
>             m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING;
>         }
>         if (m_touchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
>             // Scroll to follow the motion event
>             final int m_deltaX = (int) (m_lastMotionX - m_x);
>             m_lastMotionX = m_x;
>             final int m_scrollX = getScrollX();
>             if (m_deltaX < 0) {
>                 if (m_scrollX > 0) {
>                     scrollBy(Math.max(-m_scrollX, m_deltaX), 0);
>                 }
>             } else if (m_deltaX > 0) {
>                 final int m_availableToScroll = getChildAt(
>                         getChildCount() - 1).getRight()
>                         - m_scrollX - getWidth();
>                 if (m_availableToScroll > 0) {
>                     scrollBy(Math.min(m_availableToScroll, m_deltaX), 0);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
>         if (m_touchState == TOUCH_STATE_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLING) {
>             final VelocityTracker m_velocityTrack = m_velocityTracker;
>             m_velocityTrack.computeCurrentVelocity(
>                     VELOCITY_UNIT_PIXELS_PER_SECOND, m_maximumVelocity);
>             int m_velocityX = (int) m_velocityTrack.getXVelocity();
>             if (m_velocityX > m_densityAdjustedSnapVelocity
>                     && m_currentScreen > 0) {
>                 // Fling hard enough to move left
>                 snapToScreen(m_currentScreen - 1);
>             } else if (m_velocityX < -m_densityAdjustedSnapVelocity
>                     && m_currentScreen < getChildCount() - 1) {
>                 // Fling hard enough to move right
>                 snapToScreen(m_currentScreen + 1);
>             } else {
>                 snapToDestination();
>             }
>             if (m_velocityTracker != null) {
>                 m_velocityTracker.recycle();
>                 m_velocityTracker = null;
>             }
>         }
>         m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
>         break;
>     case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
>         m_touchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
>         break;
>     default:
>         break;
>     }
>     return true;
> }
> @Override
> public void computeScroll() {
>     if (m_scroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
>         scrollTo(m_scroller.getCurrX(), m_scroller.getCurrY());
>         postInvalidate();
>     } else if (m_nextScreen != INVALID_SCREEN) {
>         m_currentScreen = Math.max(0,
>                 Math.min(m_nextScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
>         // Notify observer about screen change
>         if (m_onScreenSwitchListener != null) {
>             m_onScreenSwitchListener.onScreenSwitched(m_currentScreen);
>         }
>         m_nextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * Returns the index of the currently displayed screen.
>  * 
>  * @return The index of the currently displayed screen.
>  */
> public int getCurrentScreen() {
>     return m_currentScreen;
> }
> /**
>  * Sets the current screen.
>  * 
>  * @param p_currentScreen
>  *            The new screen.
>  * @param p_animate
>  *            True to smoothly scroll to the screen, false to snap instantly
>  */
> public void setCurrentScreen(final int p_currentScreen,
>         final boolean p_animate) {
>     m_currentScreen = Math.max(0,
>             Math.min(p_currentScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
>     if (p_animate) {
>         snapToScreen(p_currentScreen, ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS);
>     } else {
>         scrollTo(m_currentScreen * getWidth(), 0);
>     }
>     invalidate();
> }
> /**
>  * Sets the {@link OnScreenSwitchListener}.
>  * 
>  * @param onScreenSwitchListener
>  *            The listener for switch events.
>  */
> public void setOnScreenSwitchListener(
>         final OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener) {
>     m_onScreenSwitchListener = onScreenSwitchListener;
> }
> /**
>  * Snaps to the screen we think the user wants (the current screen for very
>  * small movements; the next/prev screen for bigger movements).
>  */
> private void snapToDestination() {
>     final int m_screenWidth = getWidth();
>     int m_scrollX = getScrollX();
>     int m_whichScreen = m_currentScreen;
>     int m_deltaX = m_scrollX - (m_screenWidth * m_currentScreen);
>     // Check if they want to go to the prev. screen
>     if ((m_deltaX < 0)
>             && m_currentScreen != 0
>             && ((m_screenWidth / FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE) < -m_deltaX)) {
>         m_whichScreen--;
>         // Check if they want to go to the next screen
>     } else if ((m_deltaX > 0)
>             && (m_currentScreen + 1 != getChildCount())
>             && ((m_screenWidth / FRACTION_OF_SCREEN_WIDTH_FOR_SWIPE) < m_deltaX)) {
>         m_whichScreen++;
>     }
>     snapToScreen(m_whichScreen);
> }
> /**
>  * Snap to a specific screen, animating automatically for a duration
>  * proportional to the distance left to scroll.
>  * 
>  * @param p_whichScreen
>  *            Screen to snap to
>  */
> private void snapToScreen(final int p_whichScreen) {
>     snapToScreen(p_whichScreen, -1);
> }
> /**
>  * Snaps to a specific screen, animating for a specific amount of time to
>  * get there.
>  * 
>  * @param p_whichScreen
>  *            Screen to snap to
>  * @param p_duration
>  *            -1 to automatically time it based on scroll distance; a
>  *            positive number to make the scroll take an exact duration.
>  */
> private void snapToScreen(final int p_whichScreen, final int p_duration) {
>     /*
>      * Modified by Yoni Samlan: Allow new snapping even during an ongoing
>      * scroll animation. This is intended to make HorizontalPager work as
>      * expected when used in conjunction with a RadioGroup used as "tabbed"
>      * controls. Also, make the animation take a percentage of our normal
>      * animation time, depending how far they've already scrolled.
>      */
>     m_nextScreen = Math
>             .max(0, Math.min(p_whichScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
>     final int m_newX = m_nextScreen * getWidth();
>     final int m_delta = m_newX - getScrollX();
>     if (p_duration < 0) {
>         // E.g. if they've scrolled 80% of the way, only animation for 20%
>         // of the duration
>         m_scroller
>                 .startScroll(
>                         getScrollX(),
>                         0,
>                         m_delta,
>                         0,
>                         (int) (Math.abs(m_delta) / (float) getWidth() * ANIMATION_SCREEN_SET_DURATION_MILLIS));
>     } else {
>         m_scroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, m_delta, 0, p_duration);
>     }
>     // sets the drawables when the user swipes
>     setActiveInactiveDrawables(p_whichScreen);
>     // redraw screen
>     invalidate();
> }
> /**
>  * Allways called when the user swipes to another view. Gets the current
>  * view an sets the active drawable / shape to the curretn view. (in the
>  * page control)
>  */
> public void setActiveInactiveDrawables(int p_whichScreen) {
>     // Getting the Linear Layout where the page control drawables are inside
>     LinearLayout m_linLayout = (LinearLayout) ((ViewGroup) this.getParent())
>             .getChildAt(((LinearLayout) this.getParent()).getChildCount() - 1);
>     // get every imageview and set the one of the current screen to active
>     for (int m_i = 0; m_i < this.getChildCount(); m_i++) {
>         ImageView m_imgView = (ImageView) m_linLayout.getChildAt(m_i);
>         if (m_i == p_whichScreen) {
>             m_imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(m_activeDrawable);
>         } else {
>             m_imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(m_inactiveDrawable);
>         }
>     }
> }
> /**
>  * Listener for the event that the HorizontalPager switches to a new view.
>  */
> public static interface OnScreenSwitchListener {
>     /**
>      * Notifies listeners about the new screen. Runs after the animation
>      * completed.
>      * 
>      * @param screen
>      *            The new screen index.
>      */
>     void onScreenSwitched(int screen);
> }
> /**
>  * Builds the active and inactive shapes / drawables for the page control
>  */
> private void makeShapes() {
>     m_activeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
>     m_inactiveDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
>     m_activeDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) m_indicatorSize,
>             (int) m_indicatorSize);
>     m_inactiveDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) m_indicatorSize,
>             (int) m_indicatorSize);
>     int m_i[] = new int[2];
>     m_i[0] = android.R.attr.textColorSecondary;
>     m_i[1] = android.R.attr.textColorSecondaryInverse;
>     TypedArray a = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(m_i);
>     Shape m_s1 = new OvalShape();
>     m_s1.resize(m_indicatorSize, m_indicatorSize);
>     Shape m_s2 = new OvalShape();
>     m_s2.resize(m_indicatorSize, m_indicatorSize);
>     ((ShapeDrawable) m_activeDrawable).getPaint().setColor(
>             a.getColor(0, Color.DKGRAY));
>     ((ShapeDrawable) m_inactiveDrawable).getPaint().setColor(
>             a.getColor(1, Color.LTGRAY));
>     ((ShapeDrawable) m_activeDrawable).setShape(m_s1);
>     ((ShapeDrawable) m_inactiveDrawable).setShape(m_s2);
> }
> /**
>  * Called by the Activity when all Views are added to the horizontal pager
>  * to
>  */
> public void addPagerControl() {
>     ViewGroup m_view = (ViewGroup) this.getParent();
>     m_view.addView(initPageControl());
> }
> private LinearLayout initPageControl() {
>     LinearLayout m_linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
>     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
>             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
>             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2f);
>     m_linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
>     m_linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
>     m_linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
>             | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
>     m_linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
>     return setPageCount(this.getChildCount(), m_linearLayout);
> }
> /**
>  * Initializes the page control layout at be bottom of the news view. Draws
>  * all page control shapes an set the active shape to the first view
>  * 
>  * @param p_pageCount
>  *            the cout of the pages the user can swipe to
>  * @param p_linearLayout2
>  *            the page control linearlayout
>  * @return the given layout filled with the page control shapes
>  */
> private LinearLayout setPageCount(int p_pageCount,
>         LinearLayout p_linearLayout2) {
>     for (int m_i = 0; m_i < p_pageCount; m_i++) {
>         final ImageView m_imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
>         LinearLayout.LayoutParams m_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
>                 (int) m_indicatorSize, (int) m_indicatorSize);
>         m_params.setMargins((int) m_indicatorSize / 2,
>                 (int) m_indicatorSize, (int) m_indicatorSize / 2,
>                 (int) m_indicatorSize);
>         m_imageView.setLayoutParams(m_params);
>         m_imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(m_inactiveDrawable);
>         if (m_i == 0) {
>             m_imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(m_activeDrawable);
>         }
>         p_linearLayout2.addView(m_imageView);
>     }
>     return p_linearLayout2;
> }
>   }
> ```

**HorizontalPagerWithPageControlActivity.class**

> ```
> public class HorizontalPagerWithPageControlActivity extends Activity {
> private HorizontalPagerWithPageControl m_pager;
> // The data to show
> List<Map<String, String>> planetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
> @Override
> public void onCreate(final Bundle p_savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(p_savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.horizontal_pager_with_page_control);
>     m_pager = (HorizontalPagerWithPageControl) findViewById(R.id.hphorizontal_pager);
>     /*
>      * You can add more views to the horizontal pager here with
>      * mPager.addChild() or in xml. When every view is in the horizontal
>      * pager just call addPagerControl() on the horzizontal pager.
>      */
>     initList();
>     // We get the ListView component from the layout
>     ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
>     // This is a simple adapter that accepts as parameter
>     // Context
>     // Data list
>     // The row layout that is used during the row creation
>     // The keys used to retrieve the data
>     // The View id used to show the data. The key number and the view id
>     // must match
>     SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList,
>             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "planet" },
>             new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
>     lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
>     m_pager.addPagerControl();
> }
> private void initList() {
>     // We populate the planets
>     planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mercury"));
>     planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Venus"));
>     planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mars"));
>     planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Jupiter"));
>     planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Saturn"));
>     planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Uranus"));
>     planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Neptune"));
> }
> private HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String name) {
>     HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
>     planet.put(key, name);
>     return planet;
> }
> }
> ```

**horizontal_pager_with_page_control.xml**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
> <com.wli.horizontalpager.withpagecontrol.HorizontalPagerWithPageControl
>     android:id="@+id/hphorizontal_pager"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_weight="0.1" >
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:background="#f00"
>         android:text="@string/lipsum"
>         android:textColor="#000"
>         android:textSize="24sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>     <ScrollView
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>             android:background="#0f0"
>             android:text="@string/lipsum"
>             android:textColor="#000"
>             android:textSize="24sp"
>             android:textStyle="bold" />
>     </ScrollView>
>         <ListView
>             android:id="@+id/listView"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
> </com.wli.horizontalpager.withpagecontrol.HorizontalPagerWithPageControl>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.